# How to use jQuery onclick event to wrap a div into a link

Tags: jquery

I have a div (id = "big-div"), within which there are a few smaller div.
I would like to wrap the big div into a link, so wherever the user clicks, it will take the user to pageA, except one small div, which will take the user to pageB.
Kind of like youTube video grid. When we click on a video grid, it takes us to the video page, except when we click on the channel profile picture, it will take us to the channel profile.
I wonder if this is achievable by jQuery.
I tried to create a  element from scratch, it didn't work.
I tried to use a onclick event, it didn't work.
Here's my code:

```
      $("#big-div").on("click", function(){
        $("<a>")
        .attr("href", "https://www.youtube.com")
        .appendTo("#big-div");
      });
```

Comment: I think you should be using anchors (`<a>`) and buttons (`<button>`) instead of clickable `<div>`s because this would be more semantic and accessible. Is there a reason you need to do this with JavaScript? Do you have the ability to edit the HTML source?

Comment: No particular reason. I just wonder how can this be done. For ex on YouTube index page, you click anywhere in a flex div, it takes you to the video, except the channel profile photo. There isn't any button in the div. More like img and p

Comment: I would do this by absolutely positioning the secondary link. See: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/h5e4dskn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can't you just use onclick of event of each div to redirect to the url you want

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myDiv').click(function() {
    window.location = 'https://www.youtube.com';
  }).addClass('blue-square').append('<div class="red-square">Click me to go to Google</div>');
  
  $('.red-square').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    window.location = 'https://www.google.com';
  });
});
```

```css
.blue-square {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.red-square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv" class-"blue-square">Click me to go to YouTube</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I clicked the red square, it still goes to YouTube...

Comment: sorry about that I edited my answer and added stopPropagation to keep the event from bubbling up. looks like red box takes you to google now.